Sex chromosome of transgender people
I have always wondered what the sex chromosomes of transgender people are. I mean, sure, the sex chromosomes of males are XY and that of females are XX, and those define those sexes.
But what's the sex chromosome of transgenders?
I have searched in Google, but found no satisfactory answers. They somehow define transgender people as a male who identifies as woman or whatsoever. But I did not get much help regarding the biology behind it.

Welcome FKcos theta. (I've no idea how to produce the character!) Please take our [tour] and refer to the [ask] section of the [help] for guidance as to our ways. You'll note that we require evidence of prior research when posting. Please edit your post to include the foundation for your implicit assertion that there is a biological basis for transgenderism, and your other findings.

@JiminyCricket. Copy/paste seems to work well for symbols/characters in answers/questions, but I've not tried it in comments.

θ - Oh, yeah. Kind of a pain on mobile, but I don't use one here ;) Thanks. @bob1

Your question contains a misconception that should be cleared up first:
XX and XY do not define either gender or biological sex
The biological basis for the assignment of individuals, or parts of individuals, to male or female is anisogamy - that is, the production of microgametes (e.g. sperm) or macrogametes (e.g. eggs). It is this generalised conception of male and female that allows us to talk about sex across from the whole spread of life from birds and ants, through flowers, trees, and algae. Were we to define XX as being female, we'd be surprised to discover that male birds are in fact female (birds use ZW sex-determination), be baffled by the nature of male ants, and completely unable to assign sexes to the flowering parts of flowers, or understand how angler fish can change sex during their lifetimes.
However, this general grounding for a biological meaning of sex is not necessarily a good fit for our more general notions of what sex means. We do not generally exclude pre-pubescent boys or the infertile from having being male or female, for example.
Social gender is grounded in chromosomal and biological sex not defined by it
That said, in humans, the distinction between male and female is usually associated with these two chromosomal pairings: males are normally XY and females are normally XX with this system forming the basis of the random assignment of sexes to offspring during reproduction. However, neither this nor anisogamy are actually used to assign people to either gender; instead we use the external features of their body. Those with external genitalia are assigned as male, whilst those who do not are assigned as female; leaving a few people with intersex features who are assigned to one or the other in a variety of ways.
But whilst that assignment is very likely to match the expected XX or XY chromosomal pairing, it is not always the case. There are a wide variety of conditions, referred to as disorders of sex development (DSDs), that can mean that someone with XX chromosomes can present as male or someone with XY chromosomes can present as female (or a variety of intermediate states). The discovery that someone has a chromosomal abnormality does not cause us to redefine that person as being of a different sex as the one they have always adopted.
Transgender is with respect to the assigned social gender
Someone is, definitionally, transgender if they have changed their gender from the one they were assigned at birth (and thus carried into later life). It is not based on whether or not their current gender matches the expected biological sex based on their chromosomes. Note however, that some people with DSDs who change their gender do not identify as transgender.
Most transwomen are XY, and most transmen are XX
Although gender dysphoria is much more common in people with DSDs than in the general population, the rates of DSDs (0.1-0.2% of the population) are substantially lower than the rates of transgenderism, which are currently as high as 2% and thus most transgender people do not have DSDs. Instead, the majority of transgender people have the expected chromosomes for the gender they were assigned at birth: that being XY for transwomen and XX for transmen.
But there is evidence of biological differences in transgender people
There are many studies showing differences in brain structure (reviewed here) in transgender people, and some reporting genetic and epigenetic associations. This suggests that there is a biological basis for transgenderism although the research does not currently provide any clear explanation of what that might be. This is not surprising as, to date, there are precious few examples of well grounded biological explanations of any complex psychological or behavioural traits in humans.

One supported idea to explain transgenderism is the homones/hormone receptors that control the sexualization of the body and the sexualization of the brain are not identical so its makes haveing a mismatch between the two very possible.
